# Using conditional formulas in JExcel

Tags: jexcelapi, jexceljs

I'm using the javascript library JExcel.js in version 4. I need to insert conditional formulas just like this:

```
=IF(A1<>0,'ZERO','NOT ZERO')
```

But it's giving an error. Is Jexcel able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use same formula comparator like javascript

< <= > >= != ==

On version pro (i not test on version CE, you can use for egal comparaison 1 "=")

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The correct formula is

```
=IF(A1 !=0, 'NOT ZERO', 'ZERO')
```